# Sending message from Chrome Extension to Content Script, when extension launched in separate window

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, communication, content-script

I'm developing chrome extension that need to send messages to Content Script and everything works until I replace default popup by separated window. After that communication on messages doesn't work.

My manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Overlight Live Reload",
  "description": "Overlight Testing Tool",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' http://localhost:3000/; object-src 'self'",
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs", "storage", "declarativeContent", "<all_urls>"],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Overlight"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background/background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "icons": {
      "16": "images/get_started16.png",
      "32": "images/get_started32.png",
      "48": "images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "images/get_started128.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
      "css": [],
      "js": ["contentScripts/lodash.js", "contentScripts/listeners.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Listener (content script):

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      console.log(sender.tab ?
                  "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                  "from the extension");
      if (request.greeting == "hello")
        sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
    });
```

Execution from extension app:

```
export const testSendToPage = () => {
    console.log('Sending message to web page')
    window.chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        window.chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
          console.log(response.farewell);
        });
      });
}
```

backgroung scipt that creates extension window:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.windows.create({
        height: 400,
        width:400,
        url: chrome.runtime.getURL("../popup.html"),
      type: "popup"
    });
});
```

Everything works fine, when instead creating separated window I'm using default popup. What's more when I try use window.chrome.tabs.executeScript from separeted window exception I've got this.

Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url "chrome-extension://ciipdholchghlckepfaecipbjleanmbg/popup.html". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.

Messages from content script to extesion app works great. How can I communicate from extension App to content script from extension separated window?

Comment: A separate window of type 'popup' is not the browserAction popup - it's an actual separate window so you receive your own page id in chrome.tabs.query.

Comment: And how can I send message from extension separated window to extension content script? There are extensions that can communicate like this in webstore.

Comment: You can use lastFocusedWindow: true instead of currentWindow in query parameters.

Comment: [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) enables communication between extensions and their content scripts works by using . Either side can listen for messages sent from the other end, and respond on the same channel. There is a simple API for one-time requests and a more complex API that allows you to have long-lived connections for exchanging multiple messages with a shared context. Also, read more on [Chrome Extension Architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) for guidance.

Comment: CurrentWindow give me extension window, but when I filtered tabs to find one that I needed it works! Thank's for help.